# How to enable Wiris Plugin in Froala Editor using Webpack?

Tags: webpack, froala, wiris

I've successfully installed and configured Froala WYSIWYG Editor using Webpack. But I'm struggling to enable the [Wiris MathType plugin](https://docs.wiris.com/en/mathtype/mathtype_web/integrations/html/froala). So far I've installed Wiris:

```
yarn add @wiris/mathtype-froala
```

And tried to require it in my script that also requires and configures Froala:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
global.jQuery = $;

// Require Editor JS files.
import FroalaEditor from 'froala-editor/js/froala_editor.pkgd.min.js';

// Require Editor CSS files.
import 'froala-editor/css/froala_style.min.css';
import 'froala-editor/css/froala_editor.pkgd.min.css';

// Require Font Awesome.
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css';

// Require Wiris plugin
import WirisPlugin from '@wiris/mathtype-froala';
import '@wiris/mathtype-froala/core/styles.css';

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("texarea#froala-editor").froalaEditor({
        ...
        iframe: true,
        pluginsEnabled: ["wirisEditor", ....],
        toolbarButtons: ['undo', 'redo' , 'bold', '|', 'wirisEditor','clear', 'insert'],
        imageEditButtons: ['wirisEditor', 'imageDisplay', 'imageAlign', 'imageInfo', 'imageRemove'],
        htmlAllowedTags:  ['.*'],
        htmlAllowedAttrs: ['.*']
    });
});
```

But afterwards I get the following error in Chrome Console:

```
wiris.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'editorObject' of null
at s.e.FroalaEditor.COMMANDS.wirisEditor.refresh (wiris.js:3)
at Object.refresh (froala_editor.pkgd.min.js:7)
at froala_editor.pkgd.min.js:7
```

Firefox shows another error, though probably caused by the same thing.

```
TypeError: WirisPlugin.currentInstance is null wiris.js:3:5219
```

I recon I'm doing something wrong but I've not been able to identify what that might be yet.

Any suggestions will be welcome.